# Multiple test classes use the same set of type fixtures in MSTest

Tags: c#, mstest

In order to migrate TypeFixtures in MbUnit to MSTest, we can build an abstract class for test methods and some other classes that inherit the abstract class whose constructors contain the original TypeFixture definitions.

Right now the question is that in the original MbUnit test, there are multiple test classes that use the same set of TypeFixture. The way to do it is to have a base class that contains those fixtures, and have actual test classes to inherit it.

I don't think this works for MSTest. Is there any workaround in MSTest that accomplishes the same goal? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not good, but you can use reflection. You will get red / green pr class and not methods, which means it's harder to navigate to the breaking test:

```
[TestClass]
public class RunMbUnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void RunAllTests()
    {
        var fixture = new YourMbUnitFixture();
        foreach (var method in GetTestMethods(fixture))
        {
            method.Invoke(fixture);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<MethodInfo> GetTestMethods(object mbUnitFixture)
    {
        //reflection code to return all test methods from the MbUnit fixture
    }
}
```